# @page :first not working

Tags: html, css, printing

I have to use two different headers in the print version: one for the first page and one for the other pages. I would like to put a header (fixed on the top) for the other pages and use the css display: none for the first page. But I have not any effect with @page :first. 
This is my code:

```
@page :first {
    .header {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

I tried also putting !important in the css but nothing happens.
What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

`:first` allows only few CSS properties. You can only change margins, page breaks and windows with it.Other CSS properties will be ignored. So i assume display:none may not work.

Though you can refer more about how to use @page and with what type of CSS properties it works.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first

Comment: Is it possible to use a other `:first` working property that has the same effect like `display:none`? Example: Positioning the header outside the page? More: https://css-tricks.com/comparing-various-ways-to-hide-things-in-css/

Answer (score 2):

According to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@page

> The @page CSS at-rule is used to modify some CSS properties when
>   printing a document. You can't change all CSS properties with @page.
>   You can only change the margins, orphans, widows, and page breaks of
>   the document. Attempts to change any other CSS properties will be
>   ignored.

And also for the `:first` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first

> Note: you cannot change all CSS properties with :first. You can only
>   change the margins, orphans, widows, and page breaks of the document.
>   All other CSS properties will be ignored.

So since you're trying to remove one of your own elements - try using media queries instead:

```
@media print {
  .header { display: none; }
}
```

https://benfrain.com/create-print-styles-using-css3-media-queries/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The problem is that I need that element in every page except the first one printed.

Comment: Understand will discuss this with some colleagues than :)

Comment: Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's a Mozilla bug.
I am not able to get margins working, even when following their own example here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first

Both pages are printed in an identical way, no difference.

Comment: It is not a bug!. It is explicitly stated that Firefox does not support this feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first#browser_compatibility